# Magento2 How to apply CSS on static block class in PWA

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa, pwa-studio

I have created one Static block and added below content in :

```
<div class="hero-banner"><img src="{{media url='banner.jpg'}}" alt="" width="1251" height="343"></div>
```

Called this static block in CMS page

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="hero-banner"}}
```

How can I apply css on *hero-banner* class in PWA ?

I can add css only HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution :

You can add class in Static block like below code :

```
<div class="hero-banner">banner image</div>
```

Please use the code sample below in your imported CSS file .

```
:global(.hero-banner) {
  /*some css rules here*/
}
```